# ModuleNotFoundError for TensorFlow in AWS SageMaker Endpoint Deployment

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

Encountering an error when trying to deploy a TensorFlow model on AWS SageMaker using a custom inference script. The script imports TensorFlow, but the deployment logs show a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' error. The model was trained using TensorFlow on SageMaker and is stored in a S3 bucket. The model is being deployed using the sagemaker.tensorflow.TensorFlowModel class. The inference script uses the model saved in TensorFlow's SavedModel format. Need assistance to resolve the error and successfully deploy the model for inference.

LOGS

MY inference.py is inside the checkpoint when I pushed it to GitHub however, it isn't in my Sagemaker instance.

```
[2023-07-10 19:28:48 +0000] [6012] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
WARNING:__main__:unexpected gunicorn exit (status: 768). restarting.
INFO:__main__:gunicorn version info:
gunicorn (version 20.0.4)
INFO:__main__:started gunicorn (pid: 6019)
[2023-07-10 19:28:48 +0000] [6019] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2023-07-10 19:28:48 +0000] [6019] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock (6019)
[2023-07-10 19:28:48 +0000] [6019] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2023-07-10 19:28:48 +0000] [6021] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6021
INFO:python_service:Creating grpc channel for port: 13000
[2023-07-10 19:28:49 +0000] [6021] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 162, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 409, in <module>
    resources = ServiceResources()
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 395, in __init__
    self._python_service_resource = PythonServiceResource()
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 82, in __init__
    self._handler, self._input_handler, self._output_handler = self._import_handlers()
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 283, in _import_handlers
    spec.loader.exec_module(inference)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/ml/model/code/inference.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
[2023-07-10 19:28:49 +0000] [6021] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6021)
[2023-07-10 19:28:49 +0000] [6019] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2023-07-10 19:28:49 +0000] [6019] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
WARNING:__main__:unexpected gunicorn exit (status: 768). restarting.
INFO:__main__:gunicorn version info:
gunicorn (version 20.0.4)
INFO:__main__:started gunicorn (pid: 6026)
[2023-07-10 19:28:49 +0000] [6026] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2023-07-10 19:28:49 +0000] [6026] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock (6026)
[2023-07-10 19:28:49 +0000] [6026] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2023-07-10 19:28:49 +0000] [6028] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6028
INFO:python_service:Creating grpc channel for port: 13000
```

Github Link: https://github.com/Its-suLav-D/Inventory-Monitoring-At-Distribution-Centers/tree/master

Everything CHAT GPT Suggested

Answer (score 0):

The inference container uses tensorflow serving which doesnt include the tensorflow package. You can have a requirements.txt file to install it or do a os.system("pip install tensorflow") in your code before you import tensorflow.